# python scipy installation failure

Tags: python

Good morning:
I'm trying to install scipy in my system, and am getting the below error. Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

PS C:\Windows> pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.19.0.zip (15.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.3MB 97kB/s
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Te
mp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exe
c'))" install --record C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-02ml9lzd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-bui
```

lder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    
      NOT AVAILABLE

```
atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\
scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C
:\Users\asekhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-02ml9lzd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\asekha
r\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vewzf1v9\scipy\

Answer (score 1):

I use scipy with py35 on windows. Rather than compiling it is a good idea to install pre-built wheel.

Unofficial but reliable build is available from
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

For py36, win32 you need numpy+mkl and then scipy

1. Download the wheels.

   numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

   scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
2. After download.

pip install numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to get packages like this installed on Windows is to download Anaconda:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

It will install SciPy along with many other useful packages for scientific computing in Python.  I've never had an issue with installing Anaconda on Windows and have almost always had issues trying to pip install scipy.